# selecting an specific value inside a css class or id

Tags: css, styles

I'm trying to write a piece of code in my style.css to select the text "register" inside registration button in order to move it a bit higher inside the button.(see following screenshot) 
I googled but didn't find a solution how to select such specific value inside a css class or css id.

[image]

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve]. Please don’t show screenshots of code, but put the [actual code in text form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186) directly into you question. And then, please clarify what your question actually is. Do you want to select the input element based on that its value attribute contains that specific word? Then go read up on the _attribute selector_.

Comment: thanks for guide. no I need to select the text area inside that button in order to style that text area (for example move this text area a bit higher) regardless of what is the text itself.

Comment: You can not select the text on its own, you can only select the input element itself, and format that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see below. Be aware though that CSS needs to be changed when you change the value of the button. It might be better to define an additional class that will be assigned conditionally.

Check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for more information

```css
input[value="register"] {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="register">
```

Comment: Thanks Gerard. yes I need to style that text regardless of what is the text itself. I need that text area gets a bit higher. I'm new to css & I don't know how we can create a separate class for that text area inside that button. or can we write wildcard something like <input type="submit" value=" * "> to include any text there ?

Comment: @IT_man2018 There's probably padding-top defined for the button somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Gerard, you are right. I found that there was a padding-top in plugin's style.css file & removed it. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

the following code doesn't change the color of that text :

```
.ihc-register-10 .iump-submit-form input[value="regsiter"] {
color:red;
}
```

also I don't know what is the correct for of writing 
   input type="submit" value="register" 
in front of class name :
    .ihc-register-10 .iump-submit-form

**which one of the following is correct ?**

          `.ihc-register-10 .iump-submit-form <input type="submit" value="register">`

or

`.ihc-register-10 .iump-submit-form input [type="submit"][value="register"]`